# SPSS converting excel (.xlsx) files into .sav files with a very large size - how to reduce it?

Tags: spss

I am really stuck with an issue with SPSS Version 26. I have an excel file with 1 event per row that has approx 1.700.000 cases and 13 variables. When I import that data and save it as .sav file, the generated file has about 11 GB, which makes running any command in it very, very, very slow.

I have already worked with bigger databases (more cases and more variables, with more string variables than this one) and I never have that issue before.

Is there any way to identify what is causing the file to have such big size and reducing it somehow?

I have tried to save the file as SPSS Statistics Compressed but it didn't help that much.

thanks in advance

Comment: My bet is that you are importing the variables as string; BTW: you can't have an excel with 1.7kk lines - excel can only allow a little over 1 million lines: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: If you can add to your post (click Edit) a screenshot of your file's variable view it could supply a hint to the problem